# plot two ranges y-axis in a morris.js line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, morris.js

I have two series with different range and I am trying to plot it in two ranges with different scale on two y-axis of line chart morris.js. Is that possible?

I only can see one serie-1 because serie_2 is plotted in value 0 because the numbers are smaller than serie_1.

```
 new Morris.Line({

          element: dest,
          data:data,
          xkey: 'date',
          ykeys: ['serie_1','serie_2'],
          labels: labels,
...
})
```

Comment: Not implemented yet: https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/113

Answer (score 0):

Tom Lank pointed to a Morris issue; I got to another one from there ([multiple scales same chart](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/401)), and from there to the superimposed graphs at [superimposed graphs example](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/495e6f57435d8d8f10072838afc0a63468135045/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f343933313734362f313130313431332f66393463303836632d313763362d313165332d383438332d3333616561333562356666332e4a5047).

I'm not sure whether you can superimpose the graphs and change their opacity using the Morris object model itself, but for sure it is doable with plain CSS.

That said, I'd rather present both graphics side by side; superimposing them certainly leads to magnitude confusion.

I hope that helps!